# how to use IR named routes to create a "shortcut" route

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have routes which take a few parameters, and I would like to create a named route that sets values for those params.

How do i do this with Iron:Router ?

a normal route:

```
Router.route "stream", path: "/lessons/:lesson/:topic/:trigger"
```

And i would like one named route to "prefill" the params

```
Router.route "metachat", ->

  @params = {
    lesson: 'random'
    topic: 'meta'
    trigger: 'start'
  }

  console.log("Router.metachat", @params)
  @render "stream"
```

in this case 'metachat' seems to be treated as the path, not the name. And the page logic is broken.

If someone can tell me the IR syntax for this (I'm assuming its possible) that would be appreciated.

Comment: Can it redirect to `/lessons/random/meta/start` or does it need to keep the short URL?

Comment: it could Router.go() i guess but that doesn't seem ideal... actually I'm mostly using named routes for internal links.